# How to enable old style file loading in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

It used to be the case that there was no need for `import` statements. How do I enable this pre Meteor 1.3 behavior?

Answer (score 1):

you just don't have to use imports folder and everything is still auto imported as before

Answer (score 0):

As early version you don't need to import style file.But for other javascript and database files you should use import.Otherwise it may affect to your performance.You should have better understanding about import and export